# Docker /docker-entrypoint.sh: 32: exec: yarn: not found when running docker container (Angular)

Tags: angular, docker, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to build an angular app in a docker container. I successfully built a docker image and created a container from it, however when I run it I get `/docker-entrypoint.sh: 32: exec: yarn: not found`. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.3.0 AS compile-image
RUN npm install -g yarn
WORKDIR /opt/ng 
COPY package.json yarn.lock angular.json ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./ 
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
FROM nginx
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/ng/dist/dashboard /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

From what I understand `Run yarn` fails but I am confused as to why since `RUN npm install -g yarn` should install it. I am new to docker so sorry if I am jumping to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Is not clear for me in which container you are trying to run ```yarn```.
Right now you are calling it in nginx container
If you want to run it on ```node:13.3.0``` you should put it before ```FROM nginx```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `nginx:1.18-alpine` and install yarn from package manager `npm install -g yarn`

```
FROM node:13.3.0 AS compile-image
RUN npm install -g yarn
WORKDIR /opt/ng 
COPY package.json yarn.lock angular.json ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./ 
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
FROM nginx:1.18-alpine
RUN apk add yarn
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/ng/dist/dashboard /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

> Also, make sure that you change to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed yarn.

Comment: where's nginx config?